# Access a list element from an array of lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have following problem. I made an array of lists:

```
public List<float>[,] translatedtexture = new List<float>[8, 8];
```

this is a 2 dimensional array which hold list in each cell, right?

later on i do this:

```
translatedtexture[i,j] = new List<float>(){0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F};
```

what i am doing is basically create a list of floats in an array cell [i,j].

later on i need to apply these floats like this:

```
newtexture.SetPixel(i, j, new Color(HERE:translatedtexture[i,j]list.r, HERE:translatedtexture[i,j]list.g, HERE:translatedtexture[i,j]list.b, HERE:translatedtexture[i,j]list.a);
```

but the problem is, that i do not know the syntax to pull the values from list which is in this particular cell. i've tried everything, browsed forums and i cant find an answer to this. 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would access the list elements like this:

```
translatedtexture[i,j][0] //red
translatedtexture[i,j][1] //green
translatedtexture[i,j][2] //blue
translatedtexture[i,j][3] //alpha
```

Answer (score 2):

You usually use `list[i]` notation to access i-th element in list.
Use the same syntax here: `list[i]` where `list` is `translatedtexture[i,j]`.
So, `translatedtexture[i,j][k]` will be the k-th item of list in `translatedtexture[i,j]`.

The code will look like this:

```
newtexture.SetPixel(i, j, new Color(translatedtexture[i,j][0], translatedtexture[i,j][1], translatedtexture[i,j][2], translatedtexture[i,j][3]);
```

However, it looks a little big ugly. Better use `Color[,]` or use custom structs.
Or at least do it this way:

```
var colorRgba = translatedtexture[i,j];
newtexture.SetPixel(i, j, new Color(colorRgba[0], colorRgba[1], colorRgba[2], colorRgba[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
public List<Color>[,] translatedtexture
```

Or this if you want save memory a little bit (Color class have methods, and etc.):

```
public class MyColor
{
    public float A;
    public float R;
    public float G;
    public float B;
}
public MyColor[,] translatedtexture
```

Comment: You second example should be `public MyColor[,] translatedtexture` as you've moved the list of values into a class as separate properties. Also, you need to add a transparency colour too.